# Print json data from an api url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

im having problems to parse a json object to text. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
   url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    var jsonString = data;
    var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    alert(myJsonObject);
    }
 });
</script>
```

This is my response:

```
{
"results": [
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "title": "mr",
      "first": "noah",
    "last": "chan"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": "5316 brock rd",
    "city": "lafontaine",
    "state": "new brunswick",
    "postcode": 88811
  },
  "email": "noah.chan@example.com",
  "login": {
    "username": "silverlion343",
    "password": "pacific",
    "salt": "YQfKuRwc",
    "md5": "72faf6fd29f245b028655fc423919b5b",
    "sha1": "5f9c0106ac18b7ea4a15ad53667dc49fc644aa1c",
    "sha256":   "42465b6f63942f01c96149dd7e725f5b0e5b6836e0ce0a66b62559ff8a8e706a"
  },
  "dob": "1962-05-21 10:51:27",
  "registered": "2004-12-24 02:34:01",
  "phone": "655-165-7871",
  "cell": "548-005-8204",
  "id": {
    "name": "",
    "value": null
  },
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/27.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/27.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/27.jpg"
  },
  "nat": "CA"
}
],
"info": {
"seed": "bc96983e110ad6ea",
"results": 1,
"page": 1,
"version": "1.1"
}
}
```

And this is my console log:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
>
> var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

Seems like im missing something obvious.... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));

Comment: you can use $.parseJSON(jsonString);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response has already been deserialised for you as you provided a `dataType`. Remove the `JSON.parse()` line and use `data` as an object directly and your code should work.

Also note that you should use `console.log()` or `console.dir()` for debugging - not `alert()`.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Ofc my datas was parse already! One more question, if i want to navigate through the data of my json. Do i have to acces via "data" right?
 data.results.name.title + "<br>" +
 data.results.gender 
Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. `data.results` is an array, so it would be `data.results[0].name.title` to get the data from the first item. You'd need a loop if you want to get any further items